RHEL9 - Can I use RHEL 9 with just the GPL license or do I need to get a subscription
Could someone clarify the licensing requirements for RHEL9?  Can I use RHEL 9 with just the GPL license or do I need to get a subscription?
I'm using the ISO and some packages from the EPEL repository.

RHEL is (like every other Linux distribution) an aggregation of various independent components. Some of those components - including the Linux kernel itself - are licensed under the GPL (v2 in the case of the Linux kernel, v3 for other components). Other of those components are under other licenses, including, in the case of a non-"pure" distribution like RHEL, non-open source licenses.
You will need to examine the precise license of every component you are using and determine what you need to do in order to be compliant with the license.
